# Login issues returns me previous login profile

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, iphone, authentication

I uses nsurlconnection delegates to post request I just created one class to test my login post request one I login it gives me correct profile and again I run and login with another credentials it is giving me previous profile I done understand what is the problem I am posting to ROR server

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError * error;
    jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonDictionary);
    theConnection = nil;
    receivedData = nil;
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    theConnection = nil;
    receivedData = nil;
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
- (IBAction)sigininAction:(id)sender {
    if (theConnection) {
        [theConnection cancel];
        receivedData.data = nil;
        jsonDictionary = nil;
        theConnection = nil;
    }
    NSString *bodyData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user[email]=%@&user[password]=%@",[_email text],[_password text]];
    NSData *postData = [bodyData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/login"]];

    [postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
        theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
        if (theConnection) {
            [theConnection start];
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller and view? maybe REDIRECT is the issue

Comment: I dont understand why this is happening .... i dont understand problem with my code or problem with backend

Comment: what am doing is am running the app and giving the credentials it gives me correct response and the next time i run the project and give another credentials it is giving me the previous profile why is this happening

Comment: and even though i don't type any thing in the textfields and press the sigin button also it is giving me the previous profile

Comment: I think you must debug your code.Looks like you didn't.

Comment: I have done it nearly 10000 times and nearly 10 developers are tested this but no one is getting any idea . ... After I surf internet I thought is this some kind of cache problem ? This is really serious issue.... Need solution immediately... Need some help

Comment: And I studied that iOS 8+ is failed in nsurlcache ... So may be that is creating problem if that is the problem then how many applications are working fine.

Comment: And my ruby guy is telling that I have to clear session if that is the case how can I do that I don't find any solution with session...

Comment: Still there is no help for me